# How to configure facebook custom plugin in index.html using Telerik App builder Window Client

Tags: facebook, cordova, telerik, telerik-appbuilder

I have Install Facebook plugin using Telerik app builder. It give me error as facebookConnectPlugin is undefined. How can I configure facebook plugin with my index.html and config.xml page?

```
Refer [enter link description here][1]link:"https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Facebook"
```

Comment: Do you get the error in the simulator or on the device itself? If it's in the simulator, you need to know that custom Cordova plugins do not work in the simulator.

Comment: yes error is in simulator

Comment: it does not work in device also?

Comment: Can u tell me how can I configure that plugin in my index.html.I have install it from plugin market place Telerik

Comment: Like I said, custom plugins won't function in the simulator - you have to run them in a local emulator or on a physical device. My best advice is to follow the instructions on the [Verified Plugins Marketplace](http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/facebook)